# Can´t set div width inside table row

Tags: html, css

I´m sure this is the most stupid question for HTML developers. But I´m not one of them.

I have the following table and I need to get the three rounded images inside the table to be a circle and not like they are showing. I cannot get them to be rounded even if I have set width to be on 50px. The divs are like 'filling' the table row. I´m sure that what I ´m trying to do is pretty easy. Can someone help me?:

[image]

This is the HTML Code:

```
<div style="align-items:center; text-align: center; width:300px; height:200px; margin:0 auto">
            <table border="1">
                <tbody><tr style="height: 200px">
                    <td style="height: 200px; width: 300px;" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">
                            <div style="background-color: red; width: 150px; height: 150px; border-radius: 25px; border-bottom-left-radius:50%; border-bottom-right-radius:50%; border-top-left-radius:50%; border-top-right-radius:50%;">
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                            <h3 class="col-md-12 text-center" style="align-items: center">
                                Cantidad de Gente: <strong>Poca</strong>
                            </h3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 50px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <td style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
                        <div style="background-color: green; width: 100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 25px; border-bottom-left-radius:50%; border-bottom-right-radius:50%; border-top-left-radius:50%; border-top-right-radius:50%;">
                    </div></td>
                    <td style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
                        <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 25px; border-bottom-left-radius:50%; border-bottom-right-radius:50%; border-top-left-radius:50%; border-top-right-radius:50%;">
                    </div></td>
                    <td style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
                        <div style="background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 25px; border-bottom-left-radius:50%; border-bottom-right-radius:50%; border-top-left-radius:50%; border-top-right-radius:50%; ">
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Poco
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Mediana
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Mucho
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Comment: use width:50px; height:50px instead  width: 100%; height: 100%;

Comment: @Roy thanks for that!. I cannot believe  I did not see that width: 100%

Comment: well.. i guess i helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the 50px height and 50px width on the circle itself instead of it's container you will get a perfect circle. I also added `margin:0 auto` to center them but you may not need this.

```html
<div style="align-items:center; text-align: center; width:300px; height:200px; margin:0 auto">
            <table border="1">
                <tbody><tr style="height: 200px">
                    <td style="height: 200px; width: 300px;" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle">
                            <div style="background-color: red; width: 150px; height: 150px; border-radius: 25px; border-bottom-left-radius:50%; border-bottom-right-radius:50%; border-top-left-radius:50%; border-top-right-radius:50%;">
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                            <h3 class="col-md-12 text-center" style="align-items: center">
                                Cantidad de Gente: <strong>Poca</strong>
                            </h3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 50px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    <td style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
                        <div style="background-color: green; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%;margin:0 auto;">
                    </div></td>
                    <td style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
                        <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 50%;margin:0 auto;">
                    </div></td>
                    <td style="height: 50px; width: 50px;">
                        <div style="background-color: red; width: 50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%; margin:0 auto;">
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Poco
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Mediana
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Mucho
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The table you created has width 300px, whereas the row with three circle you are defining has width 50px each i.e. 150px total. And since the table row element suppose to fill the table width, it is stretching your row to 300px. You need to increase the width and height of row td element to 100px to make cover the whole row or if you want the circle strictly 25px radius then you can add padding to your td element.